# Proof of well-ordering property

Tags: general-topology, integers, well-orders

I'm reading the proof of the well-ordering property from my text and I don't understand the last step. I have reproduced the proof here with my explanations for each step in [].

The well-ordering property states that: *Every nonempty subset of $\mathbb{Z}_+$ has a smallest element.*

To prove this, my text has first proved the following lemma: For each $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, the following statement holds: *Every nonempty subset of $\{1,\ldots, n\}$ has a smallest element.*

The proof of the well-ordering property then goes:

---

Suppose that $D$ is a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{Z}_+$.

Choose an element $n$ of $D$.

Then the set $A=D\cap\{1,\ldots, n\}$ is nonempty [because it contains $n$], so that $A$ has a smallest element $k$. [This is because $A$ is a nonempty subset of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ and so we can use the lemma.]

The element $k$ is automatically the smallest element of $D$ as well. [I don't understand this step; please explain.]

Comment: $A=D\cap\{1,\ldots, n\}$ is the set of elements of D that are $\leq n$. Say there is some element $m$ of $D$ that is smaller than $k$. Then we have $n\geq k > m$, so $m$ is also an element of $A$. But this contradicts our definition that $k$  is the smallest element of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly $k$ is the smallest element of $D \cap \{1,\ldots, n\}$. $D \cap \{1,\ldots,n\}$ can be thought of as "the set of all members of $D$ that are not larger than $n$.

Suppose that $k$ isn't the smallest element of $D$. Then, by definition, there must be some $a \in D$ with $a < k$. Since $k \leq n$, we have $a \leq n$ and therefore $a$ is "a member of $D$ that is not larger than $n$". So $a \in D \cap \{1,\ldots, n\}$. But $k$ was the smallest member of this set, so it must be that $k \leq a$, contradicting our choice of $a < k$.

Comment: Or, without the method of contradiction,(i) $k\leq n$ so  if $x\in D $ and $x>n$ then $x>k,$ and (ii) if $x\in D$ and $x\leq n$ then $x\in D\cap \{1,...,n\} $  so $x\geq \min( D\cap \{1,...,n\})=k. $

Answer (score 1):

You know by definition that $k \le n$. If $m \in D$ is arbitrary, either $ m > n$ and then $k \le n < m$, or $m \le n$ and then $m \in D \cap \{1,\ldots, n\}$ and by minimality of $k$ in that set, $k \le m$ as well. So $k$ is the minimum of $D$.